# TypeError: concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train_image_classifier.py", line 585, in 
tf.app.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
File "train_image_classifier.py", line 482, in main
clones = model_deploy.create_clones(deploy_config, clone_fn, [batch_queue])
File "/home/cloud/hoa/workspace/tensorflows/models/slim/deployment/model_deploy.py", line 195, in create_clones
outputs = model_fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "train_image_classifier.py", line 466, in clone_fn
logits, end_points = network_fn(images)
File "/home/cloud/hoa/workspace/tensorflows/models/slim/nets/nets_factory.py", line 105, in network_fn
return func(images, num_classes, is_training=is_training)
File "/home/cloud/hoa/workspace/tensorflows/models/slim/nets/inception_resnet_v2.py", line 169, in inception_resnet_v2
tower_conv2_2, tower_pool_1])
TypeError: concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

I tried on tensorflow version r0.11 and r0.12 to pre-train fine tuning inception_resnet_v2 and resnet_150 . Both raised this error. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Interface changed in TF 1.0, you must be using old code, see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/cb17d1b0e2b581b5da1d9597b7929ba764749d38/tensorflow/tools/compatibility for upgrading instructions